# What to fill for Host person or organisation in Schengen visa form

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

I am filling the Schengen visa form but I booked the Hotel and transport through Star Tours. Which one do I need to select among the 3 options as a main applicant and I paid the amount to Star tours? 
- A person will be accommodating me

- A company, organisation or establishment will be accommodating me
- My hotel or place of accommodation (if different)

Which one to select as dependents?